# WHMCS getclients searching results

Tags: php, xml, search, multidimensional-array, whmcs

Myself and a few friends are trying to use WHMCS to offer services in a virtual world. Issue is WHMCS does not provide a simple way to search for a specific client record without already having the client id, which wouldn't be stored anywhere besides the WHMCS database. the api function getclients returns results in an XML format, issue is when you search for a client using this method you can only search for firstname, lastname, or email address. Now we have tried passing the variables for firstname and lastname(they have to be passed separately) This unfortunatly returns the client records for all clients that X firstname OR Y Lastname, instead of narrowing down the one client with both X and Y.

What I want to know is how to search PHP array generated from an XML result to try and grab the client records for only the client we are looking for.

The results are posted as such:

Array ( [WHMCSAPI] => Array ( [ACTION] => getclients [RESULT] => success [TOTALRESULTS] => 2 [STARTNUMBER] => 0 [NUMRETURNED] => 2 [CLIENTS] => Array ( [CLIENT] => Array ( [ID] => 9 [FIRSTNAME] => Test1 [LASTNAME] => Test2 [COMPANYNAME] => [EMAIL] => test1@test.com [DATECREATED] => 2013-04-24 [GROUPID] => 1 [STATUS] => Active ) [CLIENT1] => Array ( [ID] => 20 [FIRSTNAME] => Test3 [LASTNAME] => Test2 [COMPANYNAME] => [EMAIL] => test@test.com [DATECREATED] => 2014-01-20 [GROUPID] => 0 [STATUS] => Active ) ) ) )

The code we try using to search is:

```
$postfields["action"] = "getclients";
$postfields["search"] = $firstname;
$postfields["search"] = $lastname;
$postfields["responsetype"] = "xml";

 $query_string = "";
 foreach ($postfields AS $k=>$v) $query_string .= "$k=".urlencode($v)."&";

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 $xml = curl_exec($ch);
 if (curl_error($ch) || !$xml) $xml = '<whmcsapi><result>error</result>'.
 '<message>Connection Error</message><curlerror>'.
 curl_errno($ch).' - '.curl_error($ch).'</curlerror></whmcsapi>';
 curl_close($ch);

 $arr = whmcsapi_xml_parser($xml); # Parse XML
 $client = searchClient($firstname, $lastname, $arr);

 print_r($client); # Output XML Response as Array

 /*
 Debug Output - Uncomment if needed to troubleshoot problems
 echo "<textarea rows=50 cols=100>Request: ".print_r($postfields,true);
 echo "\nResponse: ".htmlentities($xml)."\n\nArray: ".print_r($arr,true);
 echo "</textarea>";
 */

 function whmcsapi_xml_parser($rawxml) {
$xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($xml_parser, $rawxml, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
$params = array();
$level = array();
$alreadyused = array();
$x=0;
foreach ($vals as $xml_elem) {
  if ($xml_elem['type'] == 'open') {
     if (in_array($xml_elem['tag'],$alreadyused)) {
        $x++;
        $xml_elem['tag'] = $xml_elem['tag'].$x;
     }
     $level[$xml_elem['level']] = $xml_elem['tag'];
     $alreadyused[] = $xml_elem['tag'];
  }
  if ($xml_elem['type'] == 'complete') {
   $start_level = 1;
   $php_stmt = '$params';
   while($start_level < $xml_elem['level']) {
     $php_stmt .= '[$level['.$start_level.']]';
     $start_level++;
   }
   $php_stmt .= '[$xml_elem[\'tag\']] = $xml_elem[\'value\'];';
   @eval($php_stmt);
  }
}
return($params);
 }
 function searchClient($first, $last, $array)
 {
     foreach ($array as $key => $val)
 {
     if($val['FIRSTNAME'] == $first && $val['LASTNAME'] == $last)
     {
         return $key;
     }
 }
 return null;
 }
 ?>
```

This returns a blank result. I will admit I am not entirely sure how to do this so any pointers will help.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to "search for a specific client record" via email address utilizing their api and they now support json format for responsetype

"Please note **either** the clientid or email is required."

http://docs.whmcs.com/API:Get_Clients_Details